# Using "layer.selectionChanged.connect()" to run another function every time new feature is selected in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers

I'm trying to use the [layer.selectionChanged](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ac32339abf885be1ed2262646e975dd87) method in a plugin to run a little function every time a user select one or several new features on the active layer.

The problem is that QGIS crashes every time I run my plugin with the sample code below:

```
def function1(self):

    self.uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
    self.uri.setConnection("host", "5432", "bd_name", "username", "password")

    self.layer_query = "(SELECT * from schema.table WHERE code LIKE '03%%%')"

    self.uri.setDataSource("", self.layer_query, "geom", "", "id")
    self.layer = QgsVectorLayer(self.uri.uri(), "mylayer", "postgres")
    
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.layer)
    self.layer.selectionChanged.connect(self.function2)
    

def function2(self):
    self.layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('mylayer')[0]

    self.selection = []
    for self.feat in self.layer.selectedFeatures():
            self.selection.append(self.feat)

    self.layer.selectByIds([k.id() for k in self.selection])

    self.layer_feats = [
        (feat.id(), str(feat.attribute("code"))) for feat in self.selection]

    list_features = [code for _, code in self.layer_feats]

    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(list_communes)[1:-1], "show_selected_features", level=Qgis.Info)
```

but doesn't crash if I change my function2 to :

```
def function2(self):
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("TEST: show this message every time a new feature is selected", "show_selected_features", level=Qgis.Info)
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things in your `function2` which I'm not sure why you are doing.

You are re-defining the `self.layer` object inside a slot function which is connected to the `selectionChanged` signal of an already defined `self.layer` object.

You are creating an empty list to hold selected features, retrieving the already selected features of a layer, appending them to the list then re-selecting the already selected features in the same layer by the ids of the features stored in the created list??

Also, as you can see from the [documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ac32339abf885be1ed2262646e975dd87), the `selectionChanged` signal emits a list of ids of newly selected features (as well as the de-selected ones) which you can catch and use in your function2. I don't honestly understand exactly what you are trying to do because you construct a list `list_features` which holds the attribute in the 'code' field for each selected feature, but in your `logMessage()` call you use a `list_communes` variable which is undefined in your code snippet. I guess that you want to log a list of attributes in the 'code' field for selected features every time the selection changes, in which case you should simply be able to do:

```
def function2(self, selected_ids):
    list_features = [f['code'] for f in self.layer.getFeatures(selected_ids)]
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(list_features), "show_selected_features", level=Qgis.Info)
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much for this perfect answer Ben !
(yes my list thing was totally messed-up but I tried so many things that I got lost in the process ^^' )

Comment: @wanderzen, you are very welcome! I'm so glad it worked because I usually test all my answers but it's quite late here so I didn't have time to test fully inside a working plugin, and I wasn't entirely sure it would do what you wanted  :-)